# returning a 2D array in c++ using typecasting

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int** function()
{
    int M[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    return (int **)M;   //is this valid?
}

void anotherFn()
{
    int **p = new int*[2];
    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        p[i] = new int[2];
    }

    p = function();  
    cout << p[0][0]; 
}
```

The above code compiled but gave runtime error. So, can I return a 2D array only if it was declared as double pointer or is there some way I can return an array as a 2D pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are representing a 2D array as a pointer to pointer to int. That is a bad idea. A better idea is to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Better yet would be to use a dedicated class. But the point is that once you get rid of pointers you can return the value without any problem:

```
matrix_2d function() {
    matrix_2d M = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    return M;
}
```

This works quite well for an appropriate definition of `matrix_2d` (see above).

[Your code makes this whole process much more complicated by using pointers](http://tinyurl.com/fuckpointers), and accesses invalid memory. In particular, you are allocating memory in your main function, but then you are *discarding* the pointer to that memory by *reassigning* it with the result of `function()`: inside `function` you aren’t using the previously-allocated memory, you are using stack-allocated memory and returning a pointer to that. Once the function exits, that stack-allocated memory is gone.

Answer (score 2):

To return a 2D array, make sure you dynamically allocate it, then return the pointer.  The problem with your code is that you are returning a pointer to a local variable, which will cause problems.

Basically, you'll want to do something like this (skeleton):

```
int** function()
{
    int** M;
    // Allocate M here
    return M;
}
```

Comment: So, basically I am returning a pointer to a variable which no longer exists, right?

Comment: +1, but also, that's only half the problem. The other half is that a two-dimensional array that's declared as `int M[2][2]` is *not* the same, structurally, as a two-dimensional array that's declared as `int **`. The former is essentially a pointer to a cluster of four `int`s, whereas the latter is a pointer to a cluster of pointers to `int`s. So there is no reasonable way to cast from one to the other.