# How to pass multidimensional dynamic arrays to function in c++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I have created a multidimensional dynamic array like this

```
int N;
cin >> N;
bool ** hap = new bool*[N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
hap[i] = new bool[N];
```

And It seems to work fine , But I need to pass this array to a function ...

How should I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it exactly as you declared it; as a bool **. Here's a sample definition:

```
void myFunc(bool** param)
{
    // Do stuff with param here, indexing it normally
}
```

Then you can just call the function like so:

```
myFunc(hap);
```

Answer (score 1):

In essence, [the same as for returning a multi-dimensional array applies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13917451/1968).

1. Don’t use pointers and raw memory management here.
2. Pass the object representing the array by (const) reference:

```
void f(matrix_2d const& mat) {
    // do something.
}

matrix_2d mat = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
f(mat);
```

For an appropriate definition of `matrix_2d` – for instance:

```
using matrix_2d = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

(This code requires C++11 but the same applies in principle before.)